# Строку битов в текст в Python

Tags: python, binary

У меня есть строка с единицами и нулями, это текст переведенный в двоичный код. Как получить этот текст в Питоне?

```
binstring = '11010001100001111000011011101100'
normaltext = # ???
```

Answer (score 2):

Такая возможность:

```
normaltext = bytes.fromhex(hex(int(binstring, 2))[2:]).decode(encoding="cp1251")
```

(надо использовать соответствующий кодек в параметре `encoding=` - см. ссылку в конце объяснения).

---

Объяснение:

```
int(binstring, 2)         # 3515320044 во вашем случае
```

переводит строку из нулей и единиц в целое число. Затем функция `hex()` переводит его на строку в шестнадцатеричной системе:

```
hex(int(binstring, 2))    # '0xd18786ec'
```

Первые 2 символы (`0x`) нужно удалить:

```
hex(int(binstring, 2))[2:]
```

Теперь эту строку возможно применить как аргумент метода `bytes.fromhex()`, чтобы получить объект типа `bytes`:

```
bytes.fromhex(hex(int(binstring, 2))[2:])
```

Но и наконец нужно его перевести в строку, используя соответствующий кодек в методе `decode()`:

```
bytes.fromhex(hex(int(binstring, 2))[2:]).decode(encoding="cp1251")
```

(Список возможных кодеков в документации [7.2.3. Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).)